# Max number of combined queries in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have a search query something like this: `((q1 AND q2) OR (q3 AND q4))`. I can replicate it using `must`, `should` in Elasticsearch's `search` or `scroll` API query. But I want to know how many such queries can be combined in single query in Elasticsearch. I have around 1000 `OR` queries, will it have negative impact on performance if I pass 1000 queries in `should` clause? And is there any limit on number of queries? I know there is limit on clause of query which can be `max_clause_count`. Is there similar limit on number of queries?

Answer (score 0):

There is no hardcoded limitation.

This will depend on your hardware and data, try it and ask question if you got any error!

To improve:

- Use `filter`
- Use `constant_score` to "disable" tf/idf calcul (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html)

Just by curiosity, why do you need 1000 queries?

Comment: Initially I had one query which used to return huge amount of documents but I don't need all of them always. Most of the times, I need only few of them. The initial query used to take a lot of time because of no. of docs and serialisation/deserialisation time. so I thought to make a combined query to return optimum amount of documents. Eventually it became a combined query of so many queries. Its not always 1000 queries, it is a worst scenario. Sometimes just 10 queries. I just want to check if there is any limit over no. of queries so I can change to old solution or something else.

Comment: Maybe you should describe your use case, give a data sample and a query, so we can help you to improve it.